# handle click event on td where td does not contain checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#maintable tr').click(function (event) {


});

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<INPUT TYPE='Checkbox'/>

</td><td>

abc
</td><td>
xyz

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have to click on td where td does not contain a checkbox. How should i do it?
I used `$('#maintable tr:not(input[type='checkbox'])').click(function (event) {`

but it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried it with class instead of id?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#maintable tr td:not(:has(:checkbox))').click(function (event) {
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xc4BH/)</kbd>

Read

[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/)

Comment: I think OP wants `td` not `tr`... hard to tell +1 for nested selectors